# Неожиданное поведение функции в генераторе

Tags: python, функции, генераторы

Имеется файл с тройками чисел вида:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

и функция, считывающая очередную тройку. По какой-то причине вот такой генератор вызывает ее несколько раз, из-за этого часть значений файла пропускается

```
f = open('1.txt')
s = [1,2,3]
def get():
    print('Вызов')
    return list(map(int, f.readline().split()))

print([a + b for a in s for b in get()])
```

Увеличение вложенности влечет за собой еще больше увеличение вызовов, а замена вызова get() на ее возвращаемого значения не дает результатов. Однако такой код работает корректно:

```
f = open('1.txt')
s = [1,2,3]
def get():
    print('Вызов')
    return list(map(int, f.readline().split()))
p = get()
print([a + b for a in s for b in p])
```

Как добиться однострочного решения, вида:

```
[a + b for a in s for b in list(map(int, f.readline().split()))]
```

и при этом не получить описанного выше поведения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас не правильно стоят циклы for. Пример

```
def f1():
    print(0)
    return [0, 1]

def f2():
    print(1)
    return [0]

[a + b for a in f1() for b in f2()]
```

Вначале вызывается `f1` а потом `f2`, поэтому просто поменяйте циклы местами

```
print([a + b for b in get() for a in s])
```